# Different opacity values for Objects on the same Texture Map

Tags: three.js

In my Scene I have one big atlas texture. For my scene objects (mostly PlaneGeometry meshes) I use the same Texture Map with UV-Mapping to save some internal cache.

Now, when trying to change the opacity for certain Meshes I only can access the Mesh's Material opacity. When changing this the transparency of all my Meshes changes since they share the same Material.

Is there a different way of dealing with atlas textures and being able to changing the Mesh opacity individually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try giving each object it own material. You can `clone()` a material. The materials can share the same texture.

Comment: I tried separate materials before but the cloning did the trick! Thank you Sir Langley!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be able to individually control the opacity of objects that are sharing the a texture atlas.

Try giving each object it own material. You can clone a material.

```
var newMaterial = material.clone();
```

The cloned material will share the texture atlas with the original material.

three.js r.75